Entity Framework Migrations including seeding
So I have built my web app almost entirely successful but I still have only one issue.
I have extended the IdentityUser with ApplicationUser but that doesn't matter at all. In the configuration of this file and like 2-3 classes as this have that UserId.
    private IEnumerable<Order> GenerateOrders()
    {
        return new List<Order>
        {
            new Order
            {
                Id = 1,
                UserId = "7ec4584c-ea3f-42e3-b862-2fb1e700fb6f",
                OrderDate = DateTime.Now,
                TotalAmount = 150.00m,
                IsCompleted = false
            },
            new Order
            {
                Id = 2,
                UserId = "7ec4584c-ea3f-42e3-b862-2fb1e700fb6f",
                OrderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                TotalAmount = 75.50m,
                IsCompleted = true
            }
        };
    }
}

}
`
I have tried running only the first default identity migration and to register a user with that Id and then to apply this (second) migration, but I have custom props for the identity and it wants me to update to the second migration in order to be able to register a user.


Just FYI, you are confusing ASP.NET (not an ORM, no migrations) with EF / EF Core (ORM with migrations). Please adjust the title and the tags.

You can apply migrations programmatically with dbcontext.Database.Migrate(), but you might want to do that at install time rather than startup, in case there is any problem that needs intervention.
